# Wso2ESB : File Connector Connectivity with Samba Share Folder

Tags: smb, wso2-esb

I want to poll a file from a Samba share folder using file connector.

I have tried to poll it like below:

```
<fileconnector.isfileexist>
        <file>sehar.csv</file>
        <filelocation>smb://abc:xyz#02@10.1.1.2/home/Sehar/</filelocation>
</fileconnector.isfileexist>
```

But it is not working like this.

Comment: I do not know the solution. However to get more attention you should specify the problem within the Title in a bit more detail.

Comment: How it is not working? Also, is that a question or a statement?

Answer (score 0):

What is the FileConnector version you are using. I reckon you to use the V2 [1]. The configuration should look like this.

```
   <property
        value="smb://abc:xyz#02@10.1.1.2/home/Sehar/"
        name="fullFilePath" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

    <fileconnector.isFileExist>
        <source>{$ctx:fullFilePath}</source>
        <setTimeout>100000</setTimeout>
        <setPassiveMode>true</setPassiveMode>
        <setSoTimeout>100000</setSoTimeout>
        <setUserDirIsRoot>flase</setUserDirIsRoot>
        <setStrictHostKeyChecking>no</setStrictHostKeyChecking>
    </fileconnector.isFileExist>
```

Also what is the ESB version you are using? You may have to encode any special characters in your password if any for ESB 4.9.0.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector+Version+2